# keycloak-admin-client integration with Payara: RestEasy Exception

Tags: java, jboss, jersey, keycloak, payara

I am trying to integrate the Keycloak with a JavaEE application running on Payara Server Full 5.201. So far I have integrated Microprofile-JWT (MP-JWT) authentication and have secured the endpoints as described in multiple tutorials for Microprofile and Payara.

Now, the app in itself should be able to communicate with Keycloak, to fetch users in a role for example, and so I am trying to integrate [keycloak-admin-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-admin-client/11.0.0) with the application in order to fetch UserRepresentation using a confidential client.

I have acheived the same using **Quarkus** without any major issues but since the application I am trying to integrate this with, uses `jersey` instead of `resteasy` I am facing problems foe which I have not found any solutions in other StackOverflow posts.

By just adding the `keycloak-admin-client` dependency I face the following error when I call an API endpoint:

```sh
StandardWrapperValve[com.itm.da.goals.config.JaxrsConfiguration]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.itm.da.goals.config.JaxrsConfiguration threw exception
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.CreationException: WELD-001530: Cannot produce an instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher.
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.NonProducibleInjectionTarget.produce(NonProducibleInjectionTarget.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier$2.getInstance(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier._provide(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.GenericCdiBeanSupplier.get(GenericCdiBeanSupplier.java:42)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.InstanceSupplierFactoryBridge.provide(InstanceSupplierFactoryBridge.java:53)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:46)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:758)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:721)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:38)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:245)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1636)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:581)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

]]

    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1636)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:581)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

When I add the `resteasy` dependencies that are mentioned [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-admin-client/11.0.0), the application fails to deploy with the following error:

```sh
Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.CreationException: WELD-001530: Cannot produce an instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.JaxrsServerFormUrlEncodedProvider.
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:362)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:621)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:554)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:553)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:584)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:576)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1878)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1754)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here are the **dependencies:** (I have tried commenting one or the other, hoping for it to work or an error for which I could find a solution...)

```xml
<!--    Keycloak-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
      <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
      <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-common</artifactId>
      <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
      <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
      <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-core</artifactId>
      <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-core-spi</artifactId>
      <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
      <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
      <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!--    Keycloak-->
```

[Here is the link to the Quarkus app](https://github.com/varijkapil13/quarkus-example/blob/master/src/main/java/dev/varij/tasks/endpoints/UserResource.java) that is able to connect to Keycloak using it admin-client. (A WIP sample app)

1. I suspect the problem is due to confilicting libraries from `jersey` and `resteasy` trying to do the same thing and clashing with each other, or one preventing the other to work properly.
2. I cannot/(do not want to) change from Payara (to Wildfly let's say) because there are other applications that are running on Payara and migrating a server would be a big headache.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keycloak admin client library is no longer maintained and replaced by https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-admin-client. I suggest using that one as it seems to run in the browser and should run in any server.

From my experience, KeyCloak itself isn't compatible with Payara Server and can only be deployed on WildFly and related servers (like Quarkus). It's not even easy to get it running on Tomcat (https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-keycloak-in-tomcat). I expect that the KeyCloak admin client is equally hard to use with anything else than WildFly or Quarkus.

Comment: Thanks! I guess switching to the Node.js client would be a better option then. Although on github it says that the client is not maintained, the latest version on Maven was published in July. Which makes me wonder if it is an older binary with new version number.
Anyways, thanks, I guess we will have to go for the Node.js solution

Comment: On a different note, do you happen to know if there are alternatives to Keycloak that integrate well with Payara? Preferably something that works with MP?

Comment: An alternative to KeyCloak is ForgeRock OpenAM. However, the OpenAM server, similarly to the KeyCloak server, also doesn't support Payara Server and you may run into issues when deploying it. But it can easily be deployed on Tomcat and Payara Server can use the OpenAM client to connect to it, which works. You can read about OpenAM and Payara Server here: https://blog.payara.fish/forgerock-integration-with-payara-server-part-1-installation